Is there a way to use F1, F2, etc., as standard function keys only in IntelliJ on macOS?
I’m working on a Mac and I often use IntelliJ IDEA for development. By default, the F1, F2, etc., keys control system functions like brightness and volume. However, I’d like these keys to act as standard function keys (F1, F2, etc.) only when I’m using IntelliJ, without changing the global system settings on my Mac.
I’ve explored the built-in options in macOS, but they either apply system-wide or don’t meet my needs. I need a way to have the F1-F12 keys perform their standard functions (like opening help with F1 in IntelliJ) without having to press the fn key every time, but I want this behavior to be limited to IntelliJ IDEA only.
Is there a way to configure macOS, IntelliJ IDEA, or use a third-party tool to achieve this behavior?

IntelliJ IDEA allows you to configure custom shortcuts. Does that work for you? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html

I'm not sure if this is possible. Because the OS has the priority in the key pressing processing. Your OS decides what to do with the shortcut (the keys pressed): if it has no action bound to them, it then passes it further; otherwise it intercepts it and handles at that OS level.

Anyway: the Settings/Preferences | Keymap screen has the Find Action by Shortcut button on it (check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-keymap.html#other). It is usually used to see what actions have such a shortcut assigned to them. What you can use it for: see if the IDE detects your F1...F12 key presses (in that "brightness and volume" mode). If it does not detect any key presses, then ... well -- your OS intercepts them and does not pass it further to the current app. Whatever the solution -- it is outside of the IntelliJ app scope.

I have already tried that, but when I try to set the shortcut for the F1 ... F12 keys the ide does not receives the key order, they are directly interpreted by the OS.
So no solution yet.
